# Seeking clarification on a pytest assert that passes or fails depending on a later exception

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I've some reasonably complex code that can take it's database configuration from environment variables (the issue is confused by Docker & Kubernetes, but that's by-the-by)

So I have this test:

```
import os
import pytest
import re

from mock import MagicMock, patch
from nbexchange.app import NbExchange
from nbexchange.base import BaseHandler
from nbexchange.tests.utils import async_requests
from os import walk

@pytest.mark.gen_test
def test_different_db_name(app):
    """Check the main page"""
    os.environ["NBEX_DB_DATABASE"] = "kiz_test.sqlite"
    r = yield async_requests.get(app.url + "/")
    assert r.status_code == 200
    assert re.search(r"NbExchange", r.text)
    for root, dirs, files in walk('.'):
        for f in files:
            print(f"file: {f}")
        assert 'kiz_test.sqlite' in files
        #os.remove('./kiz_test.sqlite')
        raise Exception(files)
```

- The basic concept being that I can test that setting the environment variable creates a file of the expected name (which I then delete, to keep the disk clean).
  I can then use a `:memory:` [in memory] database as the default for tests.

When I run the above test, I get (trimmed for relevance):

```
app = <nbexchange.app.NbExchange object at 0x7f378bea1208>

    @pytest.mark.gen_test
    def test_different_db_name(app):
        """Check the main page"""
        os.environ["NBEX_DB_DATABASE"] = "kiz_test.sqlite"
        r = yield async_requests.get(app.url + "/")
        assert r.status_code == 200
        assert re.search(r"NbExchange", r.text)
        for root, dirs, files in walk('.'):
            for f in files:
                print(f"file: {f}")
            assert 'kiz_test.sqlite' in files
            #os.remove('./kiz_test.sqlite')
            #pass
>           raise Exception(files)
E           Exception: ['pytest-results.xml', 'setup.cfg', '.gitlab-ci.yml', \
                        '.gitignore', 'setup.py', 'package.json', 'README.md', \
                        'requirements.txt', 'kiz_test.sqlite']

nbexchange/tests/test_dbconfig.py:24: Exception
--------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------
file: pytest-results.xml
file: setup.cfg
file: .gitlab-ci.yml
file: kiz.tgz
file: .gitignore
file: setup.py
file: package.json
file: README.md
file: requirements.txt
file: kiz_test.sqlite
```

*However* when I remove the `raise Exception(files)` I get (again, trimmed for relevance):

```
app = <nbexchange.app.NbExchange object at 0x7f8f60e4df28>

    @pytest.mark.gen_test
    def test_different_db_name(app):
        """Check the main page"""
        os.environ["NBEX_DB_DATABASE"] = "kiz_test.sqlite"
        r = yield async_requests.get(app.url + "/")
        assert r.status_code == 200
        assert re.search(r"NbExchange", r.text)
        for root, dirs, files in walk('.'):
            for f in files:
                print(f"file: {f}")
>           assert 'kiz_test.sqlite' in files
E           AssertionError: assert 'kiz_test.sqlite' in ['__main__.py', \
                      '__init__.py', '__version__.py', 'app.py', 'base.py', \
                      'alembic.ini', ...]

nbexchange/tests/test_dbconfig.py:21: AssertionError
--------------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------
file: pytest-results.xml
file: setup.cfg
file: .gitlab-ci.yml
file: kiz.tgz
file: .gitignore
file: setup.py
file: package.json
file: README.md
file: requirements.txt
file: kiz_test.sqlite
file: __main__.py
file: __init__.py
file: __version__.py
file: app.py
file: base.py
file: alembic.ini
file: orm.py
file: __init__.pyc
file: dbutil.py
```

The file `kiz_test.sqlite` is clearly there in both versions, and the only change is the `raise Exception` - so why does the `assert foo in bar` pass the first time, but fail the second?
(and yes, I've checked - there's no silly thing like whitespace confusing the issue)